# problems with using the .strip(' ') in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I'm trying to make a code where it prints lyrics of a song, here's what I have so far

```
import time

past = []
if song == 2:
    for i in range(len(second1)):
          past.append([second1[i].strip(' ')])
          print(*past)
          print(second1[i])
          past.append(second1[i])
          time.sleep(1)
          replit.clear()
```

Comment: What *problems* do you have with `.strip(' ')` in a list? Can you describe it more?

Comment: what is `song`, and `second1` ?   the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://replit.com/@LilKid7129/Testing#main.py

Comment: enter my replit and enter "2"